# How to set caret position in contenteditable div relative to innerText

Tags: javascript, range, position, contenteditable, caret

When I edit a `contenteditable` div's innerHTML, it forces the caret to the start of the div. I want to move it back to its position relative to the div's innterText afterwards. I am able to get/store the caret's position, but using selection/range objects to move it back there is too damn confusing for me.

**tldr** how do you move a caret in a contenteditable div relative to `innerText`

I found lots of almost-applicable on here but ran into weird bugs with each function I came across.

Would really appreciate any help as this is the final hurdle in my project and I've been stuck for a while